# How to solve heat equation with Robin type conditions with NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation

Could you help me please to solve following problem! 
I need to solve one-dimensional heat equation with Robin type boundary conditions. But Mathematica find only constant solution with no dependence on time and space coordinates. 
My code:

```
NDSolve[{
   D[T[x, t], t] - D[D[ T[x, t], x], x] == 0,
   (D[T[x, t], x] - (T[x, t] - 100) == 0) /. x -> 0, 
   (D[T[x, t], x] + (T[x, t] - 20) == 0) /. x -> 1, 
   T[x, 0] == 20
}, T, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Mathematica returns that temperature will be constant in all region: T[x,t]=20  (but in steady state solution we will have the liner low for the T(x)).

Comment: When trying to run your code, I get a warning, complaining that  boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent. Do you see the same? Have you looked into that?

Comment: Are you sure of your boundary conditions? [This example](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~peirce/M257_316_2012_Lecture_31.pdf) has Robin boundary conditions. (it is a link to a pdf file)

Comment: Thanks to MarcoB. I try to use good initial conditions (exponential low or Piecewise[] function), and it works now.

Comment: Yuri, I'm glad to hear you got it working. Would you please summarize your working solution as an answer? This way the question will be more valuable to other people experiencing similar problems.

Answer (score 9):

Something like this:

```
NDSolve[{D[T[x, t], t] - D[D[T[x, t], x], x] == 
   NeumannValue[T[x, t] - 100, x == 0] - 
    NeumannValue[T[x, t] - 20, x == 1], T[x, 0] == 20
  }, T, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}]
```

**Update Response to comment:**

```
NDSolve[{D[D[T[x], x], x] == NeumannValue[T[x] - 100, x == 0] - NeumannValue[T[x] - 20, x == 1]}, T, {x, 0, 1}]
```

**Update V12.1:**

There is now a new [Heat Transfer tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html#509267359).

Comment: Comment please, if I understand correctly: the method option you apply is due to the fact that the equation is time dependent, not because of the Robin condition. The Robin condition is treated automatically, right?

Comment: Yes, this tells `NDSolve` to treat this as a time dependent problem with `x` as a spatial variable and `t` as time. Otherwise it tries to solve this as a purely spatial problems with both `x` and `t` as spatial coordinates.

Comment: @user21 I checked the two Neumann conditions `-Derivative[1, 0][T][0, t] == T[0, t] - 100` and `Derivative[1, 0][T][1, t] == T[1, t] - 20` in your answer. The solution only fullfills the first . What could be the reason? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, a missing - sign in your second equation?

Comment: @user21 Thanks. I assumed a positiv flux in x-direction at `x==1` and a negativ flux at `x==0`, this assumption seems to be wrong.

Comment: What if the steady state solution is required?

Comment: @Jiangming, you'd then delete time. `NDSolve[{D[D[T[x], x], x] == 
   NeumannValue[T[x] - 100, x == 0] - 
    NeumannValue[T[x] - 20, x == 1]}, T, {x, 0, 1}]`