# Error with NDSolve/NDSolveValue: Boundary conditions aren't working!

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I'm trying to solve the heat conduction equation for a 2D Steady State problem using NDSolveValue but it doesn't work with the specifc boundary conditions I need. I have a thin plate with natural convection heat exchange in 4 of the 6 boundaries of this plate (x=0, x=Lx; y=0, y=Lx).

```
data = {k -> 51.9 (*Aço SAE 1020*), Tinf -> 21.5, h -> 20.6414, 
   Lz -> 1*10^-3, Lx -> 40*10^-3, Ly -> 40*10^-3, V -> 9, i1 -> 0.19, 
   i2 -> 0.2, Ntr -> 250} // N

q[x_, y_] = 
 Piecewise[{{qmax1, 
      0 <= x <= (Lx/2) && (24.86*10^-3) <= y <= Ly}, {qmax2, (Lx/2) <=
         x <= Lx && 0 <= y <= (16.28*10^-3)}}] /. data // N

eq = k D[T[x, y], x, x] + k D[T[x, y], y, y] + q[x, y]/Lz -h/Lz (T[x, y] - Tinf) == 0 /. data

ccs = 
 {(-k*D[T[x, y], x] == h*(T[x, y] - Tinf) /. x -> 0), 
  (k*D[T[x, y], x] == h*(T[x, y] - Tinf) /. x -> Lx), 
  (-k*D[T[x, y], y] == h*(T[x, y] - Tinf) /. y -> 0), 
  (k*D[T[x, y], y] == h*(T[x, y] - Tinf) /. y -> Ly)} /. data

Tn[x_, y_] = 
  NDSolveValue[{eq, ccs}, T[x, y], {x, 0, Lx /. data}, {y, 0, Ly /. data}];
```

In this case, I receive the error message below and `NDSolveValue` doesn't evaluate.

When I use isolation condition for all these boundaries, the code works normally and I get the correct solution.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve heat equation with Robin type conditions with NDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87862/how-to-solve-heat-equation-with-robin-type-conditions-with-ndsolve)

Comment: Here its considered helpful to show your own efforts and share your code in a **[well formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) instead of images** or links to external files, so we can quickly **Copy&Paste** your code, test it, and  see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question accordingly. This [question in Meta](https://wolfr.am/v57TjMS9) could be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately you do not specify all variables (what is `qmax`), so I an not help with code, but you should look at using `NeumannValue` for your Robin boundary condition.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. In my case, qmax1 and qmax2 are constant values (could be tested with any value).

Comment: In relation to NeumannValue, I've already tried to use it but it does not work. The examples about it only contemplate this condition in just one boundary (and I have heat exchange by natural convection in 4 boundaries).